# Unable to assign data to object when outside of subscribe method scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am able to assign data to this.basicdata when I am in subscribe method but when I console.log it outside the scubscribe it gives undefined.

Here is my typescript code:

```
id: string;
    substance: string;
    subscription: Subscription;
    basicData: IBasicData;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _sharedService: SharedService,
              public packAndPriceService: PacksAndPricesService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = params.get('id');
      this.substance = params.get('selectedType');
  });
  this.subscription = 
  this.packAndPriceService.searchDrugByBasicDataId(this.id).subscribe((data: IBasicData) => {
      this.basicData = data;
  });
  console.log(this.basicData);
  }
```

Here is the service code:

```
 searchDrugByBasicDataId(searchString: string): Observable<IBasicData> {
        return this._httpClient.get<IBasicData>(this.baseUrl+'v1/drug/search-drug-id/'+searchString);
    }
```

If I do this it's giving me error that undefined property drugName

```
this.subscription = this.packAndPriceService.searchDrugByBasicDataId(this.id).subscribe((data: IBasicData) => {
              this.basicData = data;
          });
          const selectionData = new SearchSelectedItem();
          selectionData.selectedType = this.selectedType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.selectedType.slice(1);
          selectionData.name = this.basicData.drugName;
          selectionData.id = this.id;
          this._sharedService.emitChange(selectionData);
```

If I move the code inside subscribe then it works.

Comment: Possible to provide stackblitz example?

Comment: I cannot because it's all connected. Let me add service code also.

Comment: Nothing looks bad. I think outside console statement executing before console statements which you written in subscribe. This happens because it'll take time to get data from API

Comment: But using basicdata inside subscirbe works but if I use basicdata outside it also give undefined error.

Comment: let me provide you the code

Comment: because the log statement isnt awaiting the api call to finish.  Javascript doesnt natively wait for requests to finish before moving to the next line so it's just getting to the console before it gets the actual data.

Comment: @Patrick see my edited code I put an example at the end of the code.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq yes but you have nothing to await the results. searchDrugByBasicDataId isnt async nor do you have an await to make it wait.  Everything will happen in order with no pauses unless directed otherwise.

Comment: What is the end goal? There is no way to use basicData before the call returns because it doesnt exist yet.

Comment: @ukn once I have basicdata I want to assign it to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example:

```
let name: string | undefined = undefined;
const mockHttpRequest$ = of('someHTTPResponse').pipe(delay(100));

mockHttpRequest$.subscribe(() => {
  name = 'Dave';
  console.log('I will be executed Second: ', name)
});

console.log('I will be executed First: ', name);
```

The output will be:

```
//I will be executed First: undefined
//I will be executed Second:: Dave
```

When you `subscribe` to an `observable`, that code running is asynchronous, meaning, it will run sometime in the future, the outer `console.log` runs first, because is **synchronous**.

The behavior you are having with your code is 100% correct, is expected. That's how `observables` work. If you need to do something with the observable data before subscribing, you can `pipe` it and apply all the necessary rxjs [operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators). If you need to do something with `this.basicData`, you need to handle it while you are subscribing. I could suggest ways of handling your code but, I don't know exactly (based on your code) when and how are you going to use `this.basicData`

If you need to show it on your template HTML, then store the observable result, and let the HTML handle it using the `async` pipe, with that, you don't handle the subscription:

```js
basicData$!: Observable<IBasicData>

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.basicData$ = this.searchDrugByBasicDataId(this.id);
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf={ basicData$ | async as myData }>
 <div>
   <p>myData.someProperty1</p>
   <p>myData.someProperty2</p>
   ...
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

You can learn more about observables [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Comment: It's just I want to assign basic data received from subscribing to the local object I created. It's very simple what I want to achieve. this is assigned to this.basicdata when I use it I get undefined. I used pipe and map but not helped.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq "I used pipe and map but not helped" why did you use `pipe` and `map`? Do you know when to use those? Do you know how `observables` work? You seem shocked with the results you are getting... this gives me the idea you don't know the basics, that is why I shared the links for rxjs and Angular observables... read them!

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq once you store data into `this.basicData`, what then? you wanna show it in the template HTML? are you going to pass it around to another function?

Comment: I know pipe and maps. I used it many times. You said "you can pipe it" I just checked if it helps. And yes I have to use this.basicdata I want to show it in the HTML template.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq, the question was WHY did you pipe it and map it.... why? using those will not change the "issue" you are facing... it doesn't matter. I have updated my answer, you are saying to want to display `this.basicData` in your template HTML, then do it using the async pipe. Please, read the documentation about observables,

Comment: Oh God forgive me :) If I said so. I am still learning it. Now you gave the right answer. That's what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247403/discussion-between-alamzaib-farooq-and-andres2142).

Answer (score 0):

### In .ts file

```
     id: string;
    substance: string;
    subscription: Subscription;
    basicData: IBasicData;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _sharedService: SharedService,
              public packAndPriceService: PacksAndPricesService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = params.get('id');
      this.substance = params.get('selectedType');
  });
  this.getSearchDrugByBasicDataId();
  console.log(this.basicData);
  }
  async getSearchDrugByBasicDataId() {
    this.subscription =await this.packAndPriceService.searchDrugByBasicDataId(this.id).subscribe((data: IBasicData) => {
      this.basicData = data;
    });
    console.log(this.basicData)
  }
```

Comment: Check and debug above code also suggesting to go through async await topics in angular

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Has same error.

Comment: Please provide stackblitz example. Don't worry about API, use different mock API from the internet